# Bash reads quotes inside a variable as text, not quotes? Is "Implicit quoting" a thing in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I've got a bash script that cleans up the mail queue periodically.  For Reasons, we've elected to delete any email to @mms.att.net and other email2SMS gateways that are over 9 hours in the queue and still not delivered.

Simplified, the script does this:

```
domains=`cat /etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt`
egrep $domains /var/log/maillog | .... other tasks
```

and the content of `/etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt` is exactly

```
"mms.att.net|vtxt.com|vtext.com|vzwpix.com"
```

---

So the egrep line should be this, which is exactly what I'd type at the command line.

```
egrep "mms.att.net|vtxt.com|vtext.com|vzwpix.com" file | ...
```

---

If I ran it like this, then it's a 5+ stage pipeline of commands each reading stdin from the previous stdout.  This is clearly not the search I want to do.

```
egrep  mms.att.net|vtxt.com|vtext.com|vzwpix.com  file | ...
```

---

However when run, the two double quotes are treated differently - they become part of the string, so we're essentially searching for

- "mms.att.net
- vtxt.com
- vtext.com
- vzwpix.com"

Clearly I've misunderstood how quoting works - the resolution was to change the included line to remove the double quotes, resulting in a line that should not work, but does.

I've tried testing by piping to `od -a` which does not show any non-printing characters.

Why does it work, making the content of `/etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt` is exactly

```
mms.att.net|vtxt.com|vtext.com|vzwpix.com
```

when it should be a long pipeline to failure as written?

Comment: Aside - why are we fiddling the mailqueue directly?   Because these ~4 domains all outsource their email to SMS gateway services to cloudfilter.net which has very low limits for messages/hour and old messages are better-off deleted if undelivered.

Comment: Yes; since the file contains quotes, `var=$(cat file)` will put the quotes into `var`. The quotes are data, and not code. `var="abc"` puts only `abc` into  `var`, because those quotes are shell syntax. Quotes that arise from variable substitution, like `egrep $domains` are also not syntax, but data.  `eval egrep $domains` should do it, if you're confident that the file contains valid shell syntax with no injection pitfalls. The `eval` command will re-process the entire substitution and expansion as shell syntax and thus recognize the quotes.

Comment: 1. don't use `egrep`, use `grep -E`.  2. double-quote `$domains` on the `grep -E` command line.  3. better yet, there's no need for command substitution here, grep has `-f` option for reading the pattern list from a file (e.g. `grep -f /etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt /var/log/maillog`.  4. since this is a list of domains with `.`s in them, it would probably a good idea to use grep's `-F` option for fixed strings rather than regexes and `-w` for "whole-word" matches....otherwise you get false positives like `vtext.com` matching domains like `somevtextycomputer.net` because `vtextycom` matches.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has yet linked to [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), which is directly on-point; the reasons people can't store arbitrary commands as strings are the same as the reasons quotes that are data (like ones that come from a variable) and quotes that are syntax (typed into your source code) can't substitute for each other, which is the heart of your problem here. You **want** that distinction to exist; it would be impossible to write secure code handling untrusted data in bash otherwise.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147903/discussion-on-question-by-criggie-bash-reads-quotes-inside-a-variable-as-text-n); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A great tool when trying to debug this sort of thing is `set -x`. Using that, we can see exactly what your commands are doing:

```
$ set -x
$ domains=$(cat domains.txt)
++ cat domains.txt
+ domains='"mms.att.net|vtxt.com|vtext.com|vzwpix.com"'
```

As you can see, `$domains` includes the quotes. So when you use it with `grep`, you get:

```
$ grep -E -- "$domains" file
+ grep --color -E -- '"mms.att.net|vtxt.com|vtext.com|vzwpix.com"' file
```

What you wanted to do is to use the quotes at the shell level, *before* the data are passed to the `grep` command, but since the quotes are part of the variable's data, they are treated just like any other character. The simplest solution is to remove the quotes from the file and then to just quote your variables, which is best practice anyway:

```
domains=$(tr -d \" < domains.txt) &&
grep -E -- "$domains" file
```

As an aside, using `var=$(command)` is preferred over using `` var=`command` `` because the former is clearer and allows more nesting, and `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E`.

Also beware that `.` is a regex operator that matches any single character, so `grep mms.att.net` actually finds the lines that contain `mms` followed by any single character followed by `att` followed by any single character followed by `net`. So for example, it would also match on a line containing `hammstattinet.com`.

So to build an `E`xtended regular expression that matches on lines that contain any of those domains, you  would not only have to remove the `"`s but also escape all the characters in domain names that also happen to be regex operators. For valid domain names, that should be limited to `.`.

Also beware that for an empty regex, the behaviour varies between `grep` implementations, but many of them would report all the lines, so you may want to treat it specially.

So:

```
regex=$(
  sed 's/"//g; # remove all "s like with tr
       s/\./\\./g; # substitute .s with \.s
      ' domains.txt
) && 
  [ -n "$regex" ] && # check it's not empty 
  grep -E -- "$regex" file
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `|`s with newlines and use the `-F` option of `grep` (formerly `fgrep`) to look for `F`ixed strings:

```
domains=$(<domains.txt tr -d '"' | tr '|' '\n') &&
  [ -n "$domains" ] &&
  grep -F -- "$domains" file
```

Answer (score 4):

@Kaz should write up his comment so it can be the accepted answer.

If you wish to avoid the `eval` then I think you should rewrite your code to put in **additional** quotes. My overly simplistic rule is that every dollar sign should be inside double quotes unless you know better.

I would change `/etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt` to be one domain per line, to take advantage of the fact that grep allows a newline as a way to express alternatives i.e.

```
mms.att.net
vtxt.com
vtext.com
vzwpix.com
```

and say

```
domains="$(cat /etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt)"
grep -- "$domains" /var/log/maillog | .... other tasks
```

The quotes are only on the first line to satisfy my rule, they are not needed. The `--` is there to protect against a leading `-` inside the textdomains file. Using straight `grep` rather than `egrep` or `grep -E` to increase portability. In effect you are writing

```
grep -- "mms.att.net
vtxt.com
vtext.com
vzwpix.com" /var/log/maillog | .... other tasks
```

Comment: grep allows newlines as an alternative ? My mind is blown. I will try on several implementations (maybe just a gnu grep thing? or is it posix?)

Comment: If you have one line per domain, you can simply use `grep -f /etc/mail/email2textdomains.txt /var/log/maillog` as well.

Comment: @OlivierDulac it is [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html): "The *pattern_list*'s value shall consist of one or more patterns separated by <newline> characters"

Comment: You should also use the `-F` option so these are matched as fixed strings rather than regular expressions.

Comment: Great point about using `-F` @Barmar. I did think about using `-f` @DonHogo but as the problem was described as being "simplified" I didn't want to stray too far from the original question.

Comment: @muru: thank you! I used until now oneliners to create an -E pattern from a "one per line" list of patterns... this is so much better and simpler and readable!

Comment: @OlivierDulac glad you have learnt something and  your mind has recovered from being blown.

Comment: @icarus : I'm not sure it has recovered... 1) I always read man pages thoroughly when learning a new command (I was learning unix in 1990, and grep was probably amongs the first man pages I read, I guess I didn't grok what -f was capable of. And  2) I use a similar thing with sed (several s#foo#bar#, one per line, in a file, then sed -f file ) but it never occured to me that maybe grep's `-f` was similar...

Comment: Yes, changing the file that you are reading to one domain per line is the key here. Then you don't need to use cat or grep at all: domains=$(<domains.txt); for d in ${domains[@]} do... [processing commands]

Comment: @Wastrel I would not recommend that approach. Consider whitespace in the file. The grep is still needed as the OP wants to extract the matching lines from the maillog. Replacing `$(cat` with `$(<` is a reasonable optimization. However when I am doing this kind of thing I often want something like `$(sed 's/ *#.*//;/^$/d' domains.txt)` so I can put comments in the file. As I mentioned, as I saw the problem had been "simplified" I didn't want to make too many assumptions.

Comment: @Wastrel, `domains=$(<domains.txt)` would just slurp the contents in to a single scalar variable (or the element at array index `0`, same thing), no use applying array expansion on it. You'd need `readarray` to read the lines in as array elements. And then, when you have the array, you need `"${domains[@]}"` with the quotes to expand the values intact separately.

Comment: @ikkachu  Oops. That should have been domains=( $(<domains.txt) ) to make an array. It will work when each domain is on a separate line in the file because domain names cannot have whitespace. I apologize for being hasty. I slurp a file into an array that way all the time and there are no problems with that method. If the lines in your file have whitespace, then you set IFS to a newline: IFS=$'\012'; slurp=( $(<file.txt) ) and you will be able to process each line separately as an element of an array.

Comment: @Wastrel, as long as there are no glob characters, yes. Then you need `set -f` in addition to modifying `IFS`, and both are global settings, so annoying in larger scripts. Or you could just use `readarray`.

Comment: @ilkkachu I use `IFS=$'\012'; slurp=( $(<file.txt) ); unset IFS` just to be safe. I'm not certain that setting IFS to a newline is persistent, but I unset it anyway. I only use this on files that my scripts create, so I know they don't contain glob characters. I have text games on my website that are bash scripts. About the only external utility I use is `sort` to display scores in order.

Comment: @Wastrel, `IFS` is a variable like any other, if you set it, it keeps that value. (Unless you're in a function and make it `local`, but passing data from functions isn't always that easy.) It doesn't default to being unset, but if it is unset, it should act the same as with the default value (space, tab, nl). But then there's the issue that if someone does the naive `OLDIFS=$IFS; something...; IFS=$OLDIFS`, then an unset `IFS` turns into an empty one, changing the meaning completely...

Comment: @Wastrel, `readarray -t slurp < file.txt` would do what you're doing there, without issues related to `IFS` or globbing, and it'd be shorter too. (In non-ancient versions of Bash, that is. You need other solutions in ksh or zsh etc.)